# Would renaming a copied folder that contains a (local) git repository cause git to stop working as expected?

Tags: git, copy, directory, rename

Let's say I have a project called `Project X` and in the `Project X` folder there's a git repository.

Now, let's say I copied that project folder (using `cp`) and renamed it to `Project Y` (using `mv`), would doing this cause any side effects or stop git from working as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it git would carry on working fine, as if you had done a separate `git clone` in each location.